# Regarding syntax in c# and vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web service in c# and its working well in c#.Following is one method i used in it

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public void abc(BllNew objNew)
        {
            new DAL.Entity.BllNew().sample();
        }
```

But again i implemented above method in vb and is like this

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public void abc(BllNew objNew)
        {
            new DAL.Entity.BllNew().sample();
        }
```

One syntax error is showing near 'new' keyword.What change i hve to get rid of syntax error.Pls help.

Comment: Those are the same code snippets.... did you accidentally paste your C# code twice?

Comment: You have the same C# text in VB.  They are two completely different languages.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't have all of your libraries, but I think that this is right:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Sub abc(ByVal objNew As BllNew)
    dim d as New DAL.Entity.BllNew().sample()
End Sub
```

Comment: Doggone it!  Why the heck won't my updates show until after I post?!?  :-( ###

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession := True)> _
Public Sub abc(objNew As BllNew)
    New DAL.Entity.BllNew().sample()
End Sub
```